# show editable text if value geting blank angularjs

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

In codeignitor view page using angulerjs showing table with details from database. but have to add condition if Order id getting blank there should be "some text" and it should be editable for enter manually order id entered other its remain same as coming from data base. please check code

```html
  <table id="table_id" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" ng-show="numberLoad">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>RRD Track No</th>
                        <th>Order Primary Key</th>
                        <th>Order Id</th>
                        <th>Mapped Date</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr dir-paginate="rrd in getRrdList |  itemsPerPage:rrdinfo.itemsPerPage" current-page="rrdinfo.currentPage" total-items="total_count">
                        <td>{{rrd.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{rrd.rrd_track_no}}</td>
                        <td>{{rrd.ord_primary_key}}</td>
                        <td ng-if="rrd.order_id == 'order_id' ">{{rrd.order_id}}</td>
                        <td editable-text="rrd.order_id" ng-if="rrd.order_id==='' "> </td>
                        <td>{{rrd.mapped_date}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

without any codition geting table [image with not any condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah4I3.jpg)

with condition [image with contion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0eCE.jpg)

i want if order getting blank there should text editable in table order id  column how can i solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You compare the order_id strict with an empty string:

```
<td editable-text="rrd.order_id" ng-if="rrd.order_id==='' "> </td>
```

Check if an empty order_id is an empty string, or maybe null or undefined. Then you have to compare like this:

```
<td editable-text="rrd.order_id" ng-if="rrd.order_id===null "> </td>
```

or

```
<td editable-text="rrd.order_id" ng-if="rrd.order_id===undefined "> </td>
```

Comment: no , it cant provide else condition if its getting blank its ctreating one more  coulmn 
4  V100103    0  701-2083100-9212226   0000-00-00 00:00:00
5  V100104    0              sd                    "blank"         0000-00-00 00:00:00
like this

Comment: <td editable-text="rrd.order_id" ng-if="rrd.order_id==='' "> sd</td>
                        <td ng-if="rrd.order_id!=='' ">{{rrd.order_id}}</td>
its done by writing this but how should blank varibale editable in this case "sd" should be editable there only